# How can I detect colours in png files using java and opencv?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, colors, media

I am using OpenCV for java to take an image and save it as a .png file (could alternatively save as a .jpg if that makes any difference).
I am trying to detect colours in the saved image at certain points (i.e. "What is the colour in image "Screenshot1" at point (50, 10)"). Is there any way of doing this using OpenCV or any other java library that is fairly easy to use? Below is just some code showing how i captured + saved the image.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java246");
    VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture(0);
    Mat frame = new Mat();
    cap.retrieve(frame);
    Highgui.imwrite("Screenshot.png", frame);
    cap.release();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you may use ImageIo  to get a BufferedImage:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("strawberry.jpg"));
int color = img.getRGB(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code:

```
       BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("E:/milleycyrus.jpg"));
       int height = bfImage.getHeight();
       int width = bfImage.getWidth();
       for(int i=0; i<width; i++){
          for(int j=0; j<height; j++){
                Color c = new Color(bfImage.getRGB(i,j));
                int red = c.getRed();
                int green = c.getGreen();
                int blue = c.getBlue();
          }
       }
```